What mitigations to human body vacuum exposure, exist?
Is it possible to mitigate the damage that vacuum can do to the human body with medication or some sort of hypo- or hyperbaric treatment? To what extent can the body acclimatize?

Spacesuits are a fairly established mitigation...
